# Android App Development - Start a chat with computer device using android phone

Tags: android, ping

I'm trying to learn android and for my app i have few questions.

1. If i type a computer name on the `EditText` in my android phone, I
   should be able to ping the device (So basically i need to first
   resolve the ARP to get the mac address of the device which I want to
   ping and then send the ping as an ICMP request).

   I believe there is some command to retrieve the computer name and
   send this ping command, but i would like to do it the hard way so
   that i can learn stuffs better - It would be nice if you can show me
   some pointers to some tutorial apps and open source code which does
   similar tasks.
2. Once I have identified and connected to the device. I should be able
   to start a chat with the device.

   Assume the second device is also an android device, how can I
   establish basic message sending from one android device to another.

Basically my app will be a client and server (I guess 2 services - service listening to sockets for incoming messages and client can send out messages).

Does anyone know any sample app / tutorials [basically code examples] which does this in android.

Comment: You shouldn't need stack overflow to help your find TCP client/server example code.  But one thing to be aware of is that this probably will not work unless your device is on the same wifi network as your pc; most mobile networks won't allow inbound connections or provide known IP addresses, and most consumer ISP/modem/router setups won't either, so without an intermediate server it's very hard to begin a connection between a device on a mobile network to a PC on a consumer ISP network because neither one's connection request can be easily addressed or gotten through to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To Nr.1

I'm not quite sure why you first need to ping the device, as you could simply try to connect to the given device (using a timeout) and see if it can be connected.

I found some informations on this, [here](http://www.0x13.de/index.php/code-snippets/74-icmp-ping-in-java.html).

#### To Nr.2

So, if you want your Devices to communicate to each other, you'll want to use [`Sockets`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

But, if your App is only for chatting and you don't need to know if the last send package was successfully send, you could also use [UDP](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html) instead of TCP (So you don't need your application to run both the Server and the Client-Socket).

Although, all your questions could have been answered by doing a little googleing...